# Spring 3 - Annotation based Bean Validation

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, spring-bean

I am building a REST API. Its made up of a Resource ( @Controller ) which  returns a response 204 even when one of the mandatory field is not present.

I am using Spring 3.1, validation-api (1.1.0.Final) & Hibernate-validator(4.3.0). Not sure if Hibernate-validator plays any role here.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I have a spring controller @Controller and a Bean with @Component

```
  @POST
        @Consumes(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Response addUserData(@Valid @RequestBody UserData userDataRequest) throws ResourceException {
    ...
    }
```

My UserData bean has

```
  @Component 
    public class UserData {

        @NotNull(message = "user ID should not be null")
        @Min(value = 1, message = "user ID should not be empty")
        @Max(value = 20, message = "user ID should have length of more than 20")
        @Pattern(regexp="[A-Z][a-z]+", message = "Only Alphanumeric characters allowed")
        private String userId;

    }
```

My validations are not getting executed. When I dont pass "userId", there is no error thrown. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ultimately ended up using Jersey Bean Validation, instead of Spring. This is because rest of my code is using Jersey anyways. To make this work I just imported Jersey Bean Validation jar and added a small change to web.xml. Validations are now working.

Thank you @Manual Jordan. I will upvote your answer, since it gave me the right clues.

```
<!--  jersey beanValidation  -->
       <init-param>
           <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
           <param-value>true</param-value>
       </init-param>
```

Comment: thank you. I spent about 2 hours to solve this problem.Then add it to `<servlet>', it works well, maybe so ugly. eg:'attr不能为空 (path = className.methodName.arg0.attr, invalidValue = null)
'

Answer (score 2):

You must have the following about the infrastructure

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private ValidatorConfig validatorConfig;

    ...

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validatorConfig.localValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    ...
```

}

Where `validatorConfig` comes from

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource rrbms;

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(){
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(rrbms);
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

And finally (I suggest you consider put the error messages in a `.properties` file, such as `validation.properties` how shown below)

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name="messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasenames("classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/somethinga",
                              "classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/validation/validation");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }

}
```

Some considerations or suggestions:

- change `@Valid` to `@Validated` (see the API for the [@Validated](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html))
- Remove the `@Component` for `UserData` (that represents a kind of entity right?). Remember that for that class each instance is unique **and** any `bean` managed by Spring is `Singleton.`
- put the error messages in a `.properties` file
- from where come the `@POST`, `@Consumes` and `@Produces` annotations?. They are not in the Spring API

**Addition 01** about your comment:

- Yes, you must use `@EnableWebMVC`. It indicates to Spring create some special beans internally for the web environment. See the [@EnableWebMVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) API. Is very important that annotation. Even for Rest I use that annotation.
- About the Rest annotations, use the Spring annotations. Such as `@RequestMapping` and new 'variations' such as `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping` etc.. That annotations contain the `produces` and `consumes` attributes. I have never seen your approach about mixing two sets of annotations from Rest.

**Addition 02**

The `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class represents the XML configuration file about all the `Spring MVC` infrastructure

Therefore for XML

- `@EnableWebMvc` is equivalent `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
- About validation it should be: `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="beanNameValidator" />` where the `validator` attribute according with the `.xsd` says:

> Attribute : validator The bean name of the Validator that is to be
>   used to validate Controller model objects. This attribute is not
>   required, and only needs to be specified explicitly if a custom
>   Validator needs to be configured. If not   specified, JSR-303
>   validation will be installed if a JSR-303 provider is present on the
>   classpath.

`beanNameValidator` according with my `@Bean` *seems* should be `localValidatorFactoryBean`

Comment: Thank you for elaborate response. Do you suggest using EnableWebMVC ? even though I am writing REST API ? To your point about from where POST, Consumes annotations are from, I am using follwing- import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

Comment: See `Addition 01` section

Comment: I cannot use WebMvcConfigurerAdapter because it is part of Spring 4.3. I am stuck with Spring 3.1. Any other alternative ?

Comment: See `Addition 02` section, now for XML

Answer (score 0):

Maybe passing to your "addUserData" method, a bindingResult Object, so you can test for and retrieve validation errors. 
here is an example of how to use it : [Validation form input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

Comment: I will try that, but I dont think thats the problem, because the status comes out as 204. @Valid should recognize that userId is null and come back with 400. Updated the same in question. Btw, I have used the exact link you pasted to come so far.

Comment: Update - When I added BindingResult ( even though I dont have a MVC type of implementation ) I got following error                                                     SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response add( UserData, BindingResult )