# Spring MVC Test & AOP: Around advice is not executed how is expected for rest controller (just for invalid data)

Tags: spring-mvc, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-mvc-test

I am working with

- Spring Framework 4.3.3
- AspectJ 1.8.9

I have two `@Controllers` one for `mvc` and other for `rest`. Each one uses how a dependency a `@Service`.

I have the following Rest method

```
package com.manuel.jordan.controller.persona;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/personas")
public class PersonaRestController {

    @PutMapping(value="/{id}", consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> updateOne(@PathVariable String id, @Validated @RequestBody Persona persona){
       persona = personaService.updateOne(persona);
       return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
```

Observe for the second parameter I use `@Validated`

I have the following Pointcut:

```
@Pointcut(value=
"execution(* com.manuel.jordan.controller.persona.PersonaRestController.updateOne(..))")
public void updateOnePointcut(){}
```

And the following Around Advice:

```
@Around(value="PersonaRestControllerPointcut.updateOnePointcut()")
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={Some exceptions})
public Object aroundAdviceUpdateOne(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {

   logger.info("Beginning aroundAdviceUpdateOne - Class: {}, Method: {}",   
   proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName(),
   proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());

   ....

}
```

Through `Spring MVC Test`

When I send valid data:

Such as:

```
resultActions = mockMvc.perform(put(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                        .header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())
.content(JsonTransformerSupport.objectToJson(personaValid))).andDo(print());
```

or by

```
RequestEntity<Persona> requestEntity = RequestEntity.put(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)                                                                             
 .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
 .header("Accept-Language", locale.toString())                                                                          
 .body(personaValid);
```

Through `Gradle` reports I can confirm that the `@Around` advice works how is expected. It just watching the `Beginning aroundAdviceUpdateOne - Class ....` text in the report and the rest of the advice body works how is expected.

The **problem** is when I send invalid data to be tested through `@Validated`

Using the two ways shown above but just changing `personaValid` by `personaInvalid` (null fields, breaking the min and max boundaries, etc) I did realize the `@Around` advice always is ignored. It confirming that `Beginning aroundAdviceUpdateOne - Class ....` **never** appears.

**Note**: even when the `@Around` advice does not work, the validation process happens. I mean, there are none exception. The `@Test` method pass.

Here some considerations.

- I have the same behaviour with `@Before` advice.
- I am assuming **before** the *execution* of the `PersonaRestController.updateOne` method the `@Around` (even `@Before`) advice must do its work. It without matter the data is valid or not.
- I have this scenario totally valid when I send data either valid or invalid to a **non-** rest controller

That method is:

```
@PutMapping(value="/update/{id}",
            consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String updateOne(@PathVariable String id,
             @Validated @ModelAttribute Persona persona,
             BindingResult result,
             RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
```

The **same** `@Around` advice works, just with the following variation (note the `||`):

```
@Around(value="PersonaRestControllerPointcut.updateOnePointcut() || PersonaControllerPointcut.updateOnePointcut()")
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={some exceptions })
public Object aroundAdviceUpdateOne(JoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
```

**Update 01**

Therefore 4 scenarios where the `@Around` advice should work:

- non rest method with valid data (works)
- non rest method with invalid data (works)
- rest method with valid data (works)
- rest method with invalid data (fail or ignored - `@Around` does not execute)

Again: the `@Validated` works how is expected for rest and non rest methods. The **problem** is about the `@Around` advice, it does not work **when** the `Rest` method is executed just when invalid data is sent. What is wrong? or missing?

**Update 02**

`@Validated` is:

> Variant of JSR-303's Valid, supporting the specification of validation
>   groups. Designed for convenient use with Spring's JSR-303 support but
>   not JSR-303 specific

It from its [API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html)

Seems is not an `AOP` annotation. Is just a Spring annotation. My `@Pointcut` does not care or check about annotations. It uses `updateOne(..)`

**Update 03**

Even adding

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Transactional
@Order(0)
class PersonaRestControllerAspect {
```

Does not work how is expected.

**Update 04**

I have

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

...

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validatorConfig.localValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

...
```

Where the `Validator` comes from:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(){
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(rrbms);
    return localValidatorFactoryBean;
}
```

That `rrbms` is a `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` instance that load many `.properties` files, one of them is `"classpath:/com/manuel/jordan/validation/validation"`.

Comment: Can you provide configuration that used to process `@Validated` annotations?

Comment: Pls be more specific, what kind of configuration you mean? Remember that the Rest method is called if I send valid or invalid data, the `@Validated` works how is expected. The problem is with the `@Around` advice. Most of the configuration is how has been described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39842293/3665178

Comment: See `Update 01` section.

Comment: I mean how does @Validated annotation works? Is it AOP too?

Comment: See `Update 02` section (re read `Update 01` section, just in case too)

Comment: it's look like AOP because [MethodValidationPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html) seems to be used. And if it is then you simply need to define execution order for your advices.

Comment: I will try adding `@Order(0)` for my `@Aspect`, seems you are correct, because all the superclasses of that `MethodValidationPostProcessor` belongs to their own packages and all of them contain the `aop` term.

Comment: See `Update 03` section. I don't know what to do..

Comment: I will try to find the answer but need to repeat Validation configuration first.

Comment: See `Update 04` section. Thanks

Comment: The other reply (answer is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the **expected** behavior. If you use `@Validated` without an accompanying `BindingResult` parameter, the method is never called. You get an exception if the data is invalid. After all that's the whole point of validation. And if the method is not called, then your advice will not be executed either.

Comment: The Rest method is called if I send valid or invalid data, the `@Validated` works how is expected. The problem is with the `@Around` advice.

Comment: See `Update 01` section.

Comment: @ManuelJordan Without a `BindingResult` parameter the method is not (supposed to be) called when the data is invalid. It wouldn't make any sense. If it really is called in your case, then that's a problem.

Comment: Your solution works. Really wondered about this. I did realize about this situation when I have added the `@Pointcut` and `@Around` components. How I said the process about validation in the **rest** `updateOne` method works how is expected with and without `AspectJ` (I have many `@Test`, methods all pass). I thought that `BindingResult` was only mandatory for **non**-rest methods. Here really wondered how the `BindingResult` has affected a `@Around` advice

Comment: How a consequence, within the rest method, in the `if(result.hasErrors()){` block added I must throw manually a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` object. Of course my `@ControllerAdvice` with the `@ExceptionHandler` do the rest of the job.